# How to use multiple relations in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Can some one tell me how to use multiple relations in Laravel
Im try explain the situation
Im have 3 tables in database as like users, orders and order products
Each of these tables is linked by a foreign key.
Im have response like this

```
address: "test"
birthday: "01-01-2020"
created_at: null
email: "admin@admin.com"
email_verified_at: null
id: 1
name: "Admin"
orders: [,…]
0: {id: 73, user_id: 1, orderNumber: "2180673", total: "350", status: "1", delivery: "1", comment: null,…}
comment: null
created_at: "2020-05-13T20:27:28.000000Z"
delivery: "1"
id: 73
orderNumber: "2180673"
status: "1"
total: "350"
updated_at: "2020-05-13T20:27:28.000000Z"
user_id: 1
phone: "+380991111111"
role: "admin"
surname: "Admin"
uniqueId: null
updated_at: null
```

Is it possible to get response like this

```
address: "test"
birthday: "01-01-2020"
created_at: null
email: "admin@admin.com"
email_verified_at: null
id: 1
name: "Admin"
orders: [,…]
0: {id: 73, user_id: 1, orderNumber: "2180673", total: "350", status: "1", delivery: "1", comment: null,…}
comment: null
created_at: "2020-05-13T20:27:28.000000Z"
delivery: "1"
id: 73
orderNumber: "2180673"
order_products: [{id: 3, order_id: 73, product_id: 1, quantity: "1", name: "Test", price: "250",…},…]
0: {id: 3, order_id: 73, product_id: 1, quantity: "1", name: "Test", price: "250",…}
1: {id: 4, order_id: 73, product_id: 2, quantity: "1", name: "Test2", price: "100",…}
status: "1"
total: "350"
updated_at: "2020-05-13T20:27:28.000000Z"
user_id: 1
phone: "+380991111111"
role: "admin"
surname: "Admin"
uniqueId: null
updated_at: null
```

This is my code in User model file

```
 public function orders()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

This is my code in Order model file

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}

public function orderProducts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct', 'order_id', 'id');
}
```

This is my code in OrderProduct model file

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order', 'order_id', 'id');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

If someone have info about this it will be so great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eager load the relations but the response will be slightly different from what your're expecting. As far your question goes, try eager load the table like -

```php
$userOrderProducts = App\User::with(['orders', 'orders.orderProducts'])->select('users.*')->get();
ddd($userOrderProducts);
```

This way you will get collection of users with collection of orders inside it. Ordered products will not be inside the user collection. Instead this will be inside the order collection. If I to show you how the response may look -

```php
user [
  ...,
  order: [
    ...,
    orderProducts: [
      ...
    ]
  ],
]
```

Know more about eager loading here - [Laravel Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Answer (score 0):

If you want for every user's order products contained in every order, you can use:

```
$users = User::with(['orders', 'orders.orderProducts', 'orders.orderProducts.product'])->get();

foreach($users as $user){
    foreach($user->orders as $order){
        foreach($order->orderProducts as $orderProduct){
            echo $orderProduct->product->name;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want all products, that had user ordered (without looking on specific order), you can set "Through" relationship. More here: [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)